# Recursion base case fails

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, computer-science

I'm looking for an error in the last line of the code, but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

```
def letterScore( let ):
    let.lower()
    if let in 'aAnNoOeErRsStTuUiIlL':
        return 1
    elif let in 'dDgG':
        return 2
    elif let in 'bBcCpPmM':
        return 3
    elif let in 'fFhHvVwWyY':
        return 4
    elif let in 'kK':
        return 5 
    elif let in 'jJxX':
        return 8
    elif let in 'qQzZ':
        return 10
    else:
        return 0

def scrabbleScore( s ):
    return letterScore(s[0]) + scrabbleScore(s[1:len(s)])
```

Comment: As alfasin mentioned, `let.lower()` doesn't change `let`: it can't because Python strings are immutable. But if you do `let = let.lower()` then a new string is created, and that new string gets bound to the name `let`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the recursive call:

```
scrabbleScore(s[0])
```

when `s` returns as an empty string (base-case of the recursion) this call will fail and throw an exception.

**A side note:** there's no point in the line: `let.lower()` - it doesn't do anything.

Comment: True, `scrabbleScore(s[1:len(s)])` will fail when `s` is empty, but the `s[1:len(s)]` is actually ok: the thing that raises IndexError is the `s[0]` in `letterScore(s[0])`. You can slice an empty string, but you can't index it. Eg `''[0:1]`,`''[1:1]` and even `''[1:0]` all produce an empty string.

Comment: @PM2Ring you're right - I corrected the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Q: When does your recursive function "bottom out" and stop recursing?

A: It doesn't.

Q: When *should* it stop recursing?

A: When `len(s) == 0`.

Q. What *actually* happens when `len(s) == 0`?

A. You call `s[0]` and it dies with an `IndexError`.

If you want it to be recursive, it should look like

```
def scrabble_score(s):
    if s:   # Pythonic idiom for `len(s) > 0`
        return letter_score(s[0]) + scrabble_score(s[1:])
    else:
        return 0
```

**However** there is no good reason to make this recursive; an iterative approach is simpler and faster,

```
SCORES = dict(zip(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10]
))

def letter_score(ch, scores=SCORES):
    return scores.get(ch.lower(), 0)

def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum(letter_score(ch) for ch in word)
```